# Find all triples $(p,x,y)$ such that $ p^x=y^4+4$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratics

Find all triples $(p,x,y)$ such that $ p^x=y^4+4$, where $ p$ is a prime and $ x$ and $ y$ are natural numbers.

I know that this question has already been asked on another forum, but I want to ask different questions about it.

$ p^x=y^4+4$

$ p^x=(y^2+2)^2 - (2y)^2$

$p^x = (y^2+2y+2)(y^2-2y+2)$

Then: $p^k = y^2+2y+2$ and $p^j= y^2-2y+2$

The solutions I saw were different from here and they just wanted to prove that $(5,1,1)$ was the only solution. I´ll just ask what I didn't understand:

**1)**

Therefore, $p^k = (y+1)^2+1$ and $p^j= (y-1)^2+1$

And then: $(y+1)^2 \equiv (y-1)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$

So here $-1$ is a quadratic residue, and therefore $p= 4n+1$. I understood his solution until this part.

- I know that $p= 4n+1$ because I saw that was one of the properties of quadratic residues, but would like to see a proof of it if possible.
- He then says that by$\mod 8$ , $ k$ and $j$ had different parity, so $x$ was odd.

Then he assumes that $p, k >1$ and says:

- If $k=2m$, then: $(y+1)^2= (p^m+1)(p^m -1)$ or if $j= 2m$: then $(y-1)^2= (p^m+1)(p^m -1)$ and affirms those equations have no solution, that might be a property but want to know about it anyway.

Then he says there are no solution for $x>1$, then $p = (y^2+2y+2)(y^2-2y+2)$, so $1=y^2-2y+2$ and that was the triple $(5,1,1)$, therefore that is the only solution.

**2)**

He started off by saying: if $y$ is even then $ p^k \equiv  p^j \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ then $a = b =1$ and that is not possible, therefore $y$ is odd.

- Since $ 4y = p^{b} - p^{a}$, therefore $ p^{b-a}=5$, $ p^{a}=y$
- $ 2y^{2}+4=p^{b}+p^{a}$, if $ a\neq 0$, then $ y^2 \equiv 3\mod 5$, which is impossible.

I don´t know how you can deduce those things. After that he affirmed that $(5,1,1)$ was the only solution.

**3)** He showed that $y$ was odd and said:

- $gcd (y^2+2y+2, y^2-2y+2) = gcd (y^2+2y+2, 4y) = 1$ (I think this is also a property but I don´t even know it).

And since $y^2+2y+2 >  y^2-2y+2$, then $y^2+2y+2=p^x$ and $y^2-2y+2 =1$, so $y=1$ and $(5,1,1)$ was the only solution.

Sorry if I asked many things, I just thought those things may be useful for other problems. I pointed out the things I didn´t understood so that it was easy to see them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put a link to the original answer you want to understand?

Comment: For 3), use that $y^2+y+2-(y^2-2y+2)=4y$, and a prime that divides both, then divides $4y$, so it is $2$, which cannot be since $y$ is odd, or it divides $y$ and it divides $y(y+2)+2$, so $2$, which it was previously descarted.

Comment: @SofieVerbeek Thanks for your comment, I helped me understand some things, it´s a pity you deleted it. :(

Comment: In 1) he says that those equations don't have any solution because the gap between two perfect squares can't be one?

Answer (score 2):

There is a MUCH easier way to finish.

Starting from $p^k=y^2+2y+2$; $p^j=y^2-2y+2$ we note on the one hand, the following inequality $y^2+2y+2 > y^2-2y+2$ (for natural numbers $y$) and so $j<k$, and therefore
$y^2+2y+2$ must be of the form $p^i(y^2-2y+2)$ for some prime and some positive integer $i$.

On the other hand, we note the following: $y^2+2y+2 < 2(y^2-2y+2)$ for all $y \geq 6$.

So we conclude e.g., $y \le 5$ and $p^x \le 5^4+4$. Furthermore using the above reasoning you can conclude $p \le 5$ if $y \in \{2,3,4,5\}$. This leaves us only a very small set of triples to check via brute force.

Comment: How can you show that $ p \le 5$? by your reasoning $p^x < 5^4+1$ but I think you can´t deduce anything from there if you don´t have any information about $x$.

Comment: If $y$ is at least 2 then $y^2+2y+2 = p^i(y^2-2y+2) \le 5(y^2-2y+2)$; $i$ a *positive* integer , which implies $p$ must be no greater than 5.

Comment: If $y$ is at least 2 then on the one hand $y^2+2y+2 \le 5(y^2-2y+2)$. However, on the other hand, it has already been shown that if $(p,x,y)$ is a triplet, that $y^2+2y+2 = p^i(y^2-2y+2)$ for some *positive* integer $i$. Thus we conclude that $p^i \le 5$ for that positive integer $i$, which of course implies $p \le 5$.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Solution:**

First, assume that **$'y'$** is **even** , this case can be rejected easily.

Hence, **$y$** is **odd**.

Note that if:

**$p^{a}=(k^{2}+1)$**  $,$  **$k∈ℕ$**

As **$(k^{2}+1)$** can't be a **perfect square** , it clearly implies that **$'a'$** is **odd**.(unless **$k=0$** )

Now, **$p^{i}=(y-1)^{2}+1$** ; **$p^{j}=(y+1)^{2}+1$**

(if **$(y-1)=0$**, we get the case **$(5,1,1)$** )

(if **$(y-1),(y+1)∈ℕ$** , then both **$i,j$** are **odd** )

**$p^{x}=p^{i}p^{j}=p^{i+j}$**

(As **$i,j$** are both **odd** , **$(i+j)=x$** is **even** )

Putting **$x=2k$** in original equation,

**$p^{2k}=y^{4}+4$**

**$(p^{k}-y^{2})(p^{k}+y^{2})=4$**

using the fact that **$(p^{k}-y^{2})$** and **$(p^{k}+y^{2})$** are **natural number** factors of $4$, and,

**$(p^{k}+y^{2})>(p^{k}-y^{2})$**

**$(p^{k}+y^{2})=4$** ; **$(p^{k}-y^{2})=1$**

we can see that this is not possible as  **$ y^{2}≠1.5 $**

Hence no possible solutions when **$y≠1$**

The only possible solution:

**$(p,x,y)=(5,1,1)$**

Comment: Why do you say $i,j$ are both odd?

Comment: @Vmimi After we say that y is odd, see the first thing that is written. If $p^{a}=k^{2}+1$, then, as $(k^{2}+1)$ can't be a perfect square (unless $k$ is $0$), hence either $k=0$ or else, $a=odd$. In the same way I say that either $i,j$ both are odd, or else, $(y-1)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be a prime number, and $x$ and $y$ natural numbers, such that $p^x=y^4+4$. Then as you note
$$p^x=(y^2+2y+2)(y^2-2y+2),$$
and hence both factors are powers of $p$, say
\begin{eqnarray*}
y^2+2y+2&=&p^u,\\
y^2-2y+2&=&p^v.
\end{eqnarray*}
First note that if $v=0$ then $y=1$, and we find that $p=5$ and $x=1$, the solution you already found.

Now suppose $v>0$. Because $y>0$ we have $p^u>p^v$ and so $u>v$, so $p^{u-v}-1$ is an integer. Then from
$$4y=(y^2+2y+2)-(y^2-2y+2)=p^u-p^v=p^v(p^{u-v}-1).$$
we see that $p$ divides $4y$ because $v>0$. So either $p$ divides $4$ or $p$ divides $y$. If $p$ divides $y$ then from
$$p^x=y^4+4,$$
it follows that $p$ also divides $4$, so either way we find that $p=2$. Then clearly $x>2$ because $y>0$, and reducing mod $2$ shows that $y$ is even, say $y=2z$. Plugging this in shows that
$$2^x=p^x=y^4+4=(2z)^4+4=2^4z^4+4,$$
and dividing by $4$ shows that
$$2^{x-2}=4z^4+1.$$
In particular $2^{x-2}$ is odd, so $x=3$. But then $4z^4+1=1$ and so $z=0$, which implies $y=0$, a contradiction.

This shows that the unique solution is indeed $(p,x,y)=(5,1,1)$.